# Unicode font for all Languages in php

Tags: fonts

I have to print following languages in an image using GDlibrary , Is there any unicode font that support all the languages.

```
கைவிடப்பட்ட 弃 verlassen مهجور abandonado abandonné заброшенный abandonado त्यागा हुआ verlaten abbandonato ditinggalkan εγκαταλειμμένος opuszczony övergiven 버려진 放棄された relicta tréigthe terkedilmiş ถูกปล่อยปละละเลย
```

Comment: There couldn't be a single font family that supports all languages due to various limitation in font creation, however give it a try with utf-16le and also check for noto font by google and  its ttf

Comment: @NareshKumar there can absolutely be a single font *family* for this (as a font family can consist of as many individual fonts as necessary). You just can't use a single *font*, for both technical and practical reasons (linked to in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: [this stackoverflow post](/questions/34732718) on why there is no *single* font for everything in Unicode.

You could use a font stack, but I don't recall gd being particularly good at setting one up, so you really want a full coverage font *family* or at least font *stack*, with a font library that lets you ask which font in your (ordered) set of fonts contains the glyph you're about to need to render, so that you can then tell gd which font to use for that particular text.

(I wrote a library for this, but it was for PHP <5.5 and it guaranteed won't work for PHP 7, so you're going to have to find a modern one)

Comment: The stackoverflow link you embedded takes to 404,Could you check it?